# Span going outside footer - Tailwind

Tags: html, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I have a gradient that I want to include inside of my card. I've tried placing it in different positions and playing with the width but it keeps expanding more than the width of the card. Is there something else that would work better than the span? I just want the gradient line at the very bottom/edge of the card the card and for it to be responsive if the screen size changes similar to the cards.

Here is my code:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/6hZ6Mszl3z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the position of footer to `relative` and position the span with gradient to the bottom (`bottom: 0`)

--> https://play.tailwindcss.com/cvRRX4M5gB